How do I build a flatpak that is able to handle hardcoded paths in an executable?
I'm using flatpak-builder to copy an executable called "example.exe" into "/app/example.exe", and an accompanying data file called "usr/example.dat" into "/app/usr/example.dat".
When I run /app/example.exe in the flatpak, it fails because it is hardcoded to look for /usr/example.dat, which unfortunately resides in /app/usr/example.dat.
Is there some solution (without rebuilding example.exe) that will allow the executable to correctly locate the data file? Maybe have flatpak or flatpak-builder somehow symlink /app/usr/ to /usr/?
